# Document #define without the preprocessor

Tags: c, doxygen

On the Doxygen documentation I am writting, I have set `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = NO`, because I want all of the code to be documented, independently of any `#if` statements.

The problems is that there is a `#define` that I need to be documented, but since I have disabled the preprocessor, nothing is generated for it (the other structures on that file are being documented just fine).

One option would be to enable the preprocessor and use the `PREDEFINED` option to set all the `#if`, but that is not realistically achievable in my case (too many of them).

Are there any other ways to achieve the intended result?

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on your compiler you can define from the flags at compilation

Comment: @mdatsev I am not compiling. If I understood correctly the Doxygen parser does all of the work. Compiling would not fit my case either, because this piece of software is used in several use cases, and the documentation should cover all of them, not just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On the Doxygen documentation I am writting, I have set `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = NO`, because I want all of the code to be documented, independently of any `#if` statements.

That's got some code smell to it.  The interface presented by your code should be documented *according to how it was built*.  It's pretty pointless to document features that could have been built but weren't, or to document alternative ways in which your features could have been built.  Generally speaking, that means having Doxygen pre-process conditional-compilation directives.

And if you have conditional compilation that you intend for *users* of your library to trigger when they build their own programs, then I suggest taking a different approach: split your headers, so that your users select which headers to include instead of relying on conditional compilation to customize the content of a single header.

HOWEVER, if you *must* document all the code in every conditional-compilation branch in a single set of documentation, and you also want to document macros, then you could consider leaving preprocessing on, and filtering out the conditional compilation directives with an input filter.  The latter part might be specified like this, for example:

```
INPUT_FILTER = "sed '/^[ ]*#[ ]*\(if\|el\|endif\)/ d'"
```

That does not account for line continuations, so as to keep it relatively simple, but even in that form it might be sufficient for your purposes.  It could be augmented to handle line continuations if needed.

Comment: This is the documentation of a bundle of libraries. The libraries are provided in source code format (this is a pre-requisite), and the users can configure them through several defines. This is why all of the code has to be documented, I can't guess what features the user will choose to use.

My headers are already split into modules, I just need to document them all...

Comment: I am not persuaded, @AmiguelS.  If the libraries have build-time options that affect what features are available or what their details are, then their documentation should be built along with the libraries themselves, based on the build configuration.  Alternatively, if you only have to deal with which of a set of non-exclusive features are enabled, then just configure to enable everything, and build documentation for that, including in the documentation for each optional feature a notice that it is optional, and therefore may not be available in any given build.

Comment: ... or you can just filter out the conditional compilation directives, as I already described in this answer.

Comment: Yes, I will try to filter out the conditional compilation directives as you suggested. 

Take Android as an example. If you go to the documentation pages, all of the documentation is available, not only of the components that I'll be using on my project.

Comment: Quotation marks are required around the sed, like so ``INPUT_FILTER = "sed '/^[ ]*#[ ]*\(if\|el\|endif\)/ d'"``

Comment: Please update you answer, having my last comment in mind.. I'll then mark it as teh accepted answer.

Comment: There you go, @AmiguelS